# What do VCs or angel investors really do for their invested businesses?

Tags: investment-strategies, venture-capital

I have seen angel investors / venture capitalists on shows like 'Shark Tank' who make claims about how they will benefit the businesses the invest in, more than just that investment.

They make claims like "I will add some value to the product", "I must do a lot of work for this business that you don't know/understand", "It takes a lot of my time and drains a lot of my energy", "It is a good fit for me and I know what to do", etc.

Do they want to make investments in these businesses, or they would like to engage into the business? If they do like to engage, why wouldn't they just do all the jobs with their own teams and earn more money?

Comment: This question seems fine for the site and should be reopened. The position of a VC / angel investor in relation to an acquired business is no more opinionated than most organizational-structure type questions posted here. A simple answer would discuss the difference between VCs and AI's, what an investment means [beyond just a 'loan'], the vested interest the new investor has in the business, and the separation of risk and potential for unique experience from the acquired business that means the investor wouldn't want to just do everything themselves.

Comment: It may not be opinionated, but I'm struggling to see the connection with *personal* finance.